# How do I identify groups that do not fit a certain criteria?

Tags: sql

I am trying to use SQL to generate a list of records that do not contain a certain date. I have a database that, for the purposes of this question, looks like this:

```
Block House Room Date_Room_Was_Vacuumed
471   96    1    23-MAY-17 01.48.02.000000000 PM
471   96    1    28-SEP-18 04.59.52.000000000 PM
471   95    1    01-JUL-19 08.40.01.274944000 AM
471   95    1    17-AUG-18 04.59.18.000000000 PM
```

My job is essentially to find all the rooms that have not been vacuumed during the year 2019. So in the above table I need to write a query that would return Block 471, House 96, Room 1 – because neither of the date entries are in 2019 – but not Block 471, House 95, Room 1 because Room 1 has a date entry in 2019.

My very first thought was to use a where clause to eliminate the 2019 dates, but that doesn’t tell me which room doesn’t have any 2019 dates and only eliminates the one record from view.

Does anyone have an idea as to how I’d do this?

Comment: sql server? mysql? oracle? other?

Comment: It’s an oracle database

Answer (score 1):

Not exists or `group by`?

```
select block, house, room
from t
group by block, house, room
having sum(case when extract(year from date_room_was_vacuumed) = 2019 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```